# I can't delete all the data within 2 tables of a database which is in a relationship using Delphi7

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-7

I am getting the following error :

> Project PAT_p.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'tblAntwoorde' includes related records'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

This error occurs at the first execute in the following code:

```
procedure TfrmKomp.btnTerug1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := false;
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'Delete * from tblDeelnemers'; // delete from table1
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'Delete * from tblAntwoorde'; // delete from table2
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * from tblDeelnemers'; // for displaying on dbgrid that records is removed  
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := true;
end;
```

My tables in my database are linked in a one-to-many relationship where ID is the PK in tblDeelname and Nommer is a autonumber and the PK in tblAntwoorde. Unfortunately this is for a Practical assessment task at school and the relationship have to be there.

I want to remove all the data in the tables but the tables have to stay there with all of its columns. This do not necessarily have to be with a sql statement, any sort of code that I can use in delphi7 will be fine.

Comment: Have you tried deleting records in another order? Or you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` option when specifying foreign keys to automate the deletion.

Comment: As @Inspired says, you can specify the [`cascade delete`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/delete-one-or-more-records-from-an-access-database-HA001173951.aspx) rule on your table. Then you will delete records just from your primary table and by doing that, all the records in the related table will be deleted too.

Comment: I am not marking this as answer because I have not worked with Delphi in a while, but shouldn't you close and open your tquery per delete operation?

Comment: @Robert: No, you don't. Setting `Text` replaces what's already there. You have to use `Clear` when you're using `Add` or `Append`, but not when using `Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the Cascate delete sugestion I whent to research it and found a easier way [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/407201/on-delete-cascade-for-already-created-table).

All that basically have to happen is that the data from the secondary Table have to be deleted before those of the primary Table.

```
procedure TfrmKomp.btnTerug1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := false;
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'Delete * from tblAntwoorde'; // delete from SecondaryTable
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'Delete * from tblDeelnemers'; // delete from PrimaryTable
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * from tblDeelnemers'; // for displaying on dbgrid that records is removed  
  frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := true;
end;
```

Tanks for all the help with your comments guys. I really appreciate it. ☺

Comment: You didn't find easier way. With deleting cascade you didn't need to bother with deleting related table record(s). You'd delete record(s) in primary table and database engine will automatically delete related record(s) for you. Cascade rules also keeps your data consistent even if you forget to delete related table record(s). And they are doing that on a database engine side, so they're also a little more efficient than two separate queries executed.